# How can i change my flutter app theme automatically by DAY and NIGHT times

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I search everywherer but all of them talk about seting dark theme or change theme in runtime.
I have not any problems with these.
I want my flutter app to change its theme to light in days and changes it to dark in nights dynamically by sunset or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

When building your app you usually use MaterialApp, there you can set both light and dark themes with the parameters `theme` and `darkTheme`. Also, you can set the theme mode which can be `ThemeMode.system`, `ThemeMode.light` or `ThemeMode.dark`. If you want the theme to change based on the device's settings, use `ThemeMode.system`. Otherwise, you have to do it manually based on the time of the day - changing between `ThemeMode.light` and `ThemeMode.dark`.

```
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  ThemeMode _mode;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(), //or create your own lightTheme
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), //or create your own darkTheme
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system, //this should be enoguh for most updated devices
      home: HomeScreen()
    );
  }
}
```

If you want more control then you have to specify the logic of what you want and update a ThemeMode variable with `setState(());` according to the time of day.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to change app theme, you can check current time and change your theme according to it. However i am not sure if that's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
We have developed a plugin inspired by this answer. https://pub.dev/packages/day_night_theme_flutter

Follow these steps to achieve this.

1. Convert your main app to a stateful widget

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```

2. Create variables for the light theme, dark theme & selected theme. Call `_selectTheme()` in initState.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ThemeData _selectedTheme;

  ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  );

  ThemeData _darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  );
  /// Timer will be required to change the theme after some time.
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectTheme();

    super.initState();
  }
```

3. Now in selectTheme method

```
 _selectTheme() {
    // Current time
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    // Dark theme start time evening 7 pm
    DateTime darkThemeStartTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 19);
    // Dark theme to Light switch happen at 6 am
    DateTime darkThemeEndTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 6);

    // time left to change the theme
    int timerSeconds;

    // if current time is after 6 am & before 7 pm then light theme else dark theme
    if (now.compareTo(darkThemeEndTime) > 0 && now.compareTo(darkThemeStartTime) < 0) {
      // time between 6 am and 7 pm
      print('lightTheme');
      _selectedTheme = _lightTheme;
      // theme will be changed at 7 pm
      timerSeconds = darkThemeStartTime.difference(now).inSeconds;
    } else if(now.compareTo(darkThemeStartTime) > 0) {
      // time after 7 pm
      print('darkTheme');
      _selectedTheme = _darkTheme;
      DateTime nextDayMorningTime = darkThemeStartTime.add(Duration(days: 1));
      timerSeconds = nextDayMorningTime.difference(now).inSeconds;
    } else {
      // time before 6 am
      print('darkTheme');
      _selectedTheme = _darkTheme;
      timerSeconds = darkThemeEndTime.difference(now).inSeconds;
    }

    _timer = Timer(
      Duration(seconds: timerSeconds),
      () {
       //_selectTheme will be called after speciefied time
        _selectTheme();
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }
```

4. in MaterialApp

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: _selectedTheme,
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
```

5. In dispose method

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```